# awk opposite of split

Tags: awk

what would be an opposite of `split()` in `awk`?
Imagine I have array containig characters/integers.

What I've tried:

```
color = "#FFFF00";
printf("color original: %s\n", color);
split(color, chars, "");
joined = "";
for (i=1; i <= length(chars); i++) {
    joined = joined + chars[i];
}
printf("color joined: %s\n", joined);
```

however the output is:

```
color original: #FFFF00
color joined: 0
```

that is of course incorrect.

**UPDATE:**
cool, ended up with the following code (inspired by join function present in answers):

```
color = "#FFFF00";
printf("color original: %s\n", color);
split(color, chars, "");
joined = "";
for (i=1; i <= length(chars); i++) {
    joined = joined "" chars[i];
}
printf("color joined: %s\n", joined);
```

the trick was not to use `+` sign when joining things back

Comment: A few things: the `""` in `joined "" chars[i]` above isn't doing anything. Although the approach above will work for single characters in an array, it is not the way to do this in general. Using length() on an array like that is GNU-awk specific. Get rid of the null statements (trailing semi-colons). printf is a builtin with a synopsis of `printf fmt,data`, not a function so printf(stuff) does NOT do what you think it does. I'll post something simple that does what you want but in the general case.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Knowing that the opposite of `split()` is `join()`, a mere Google Search gives me this page, which seems to contain the solution : http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html . It joins all the elements of an array together, and returns the corresponding string.

```
['f','o','o'] => "foo"
```

Have fun

Comment: The linked page refers to writing a function yourself. One of the answers that actually contains instructions in-line should be accepted (gnu.org is down at the time of writing).

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on gawk or knowing the length of the array and lets you put a separator (space in this case) string between each array element if you like:

```
color = "#FFFF00"
printf "color original: %s\n", color
split(color, chars, "")
joined = sep = ""
for (i=1; i in chars; i++) {
    joined = joined sep chars[i]
    sep = " "     # populate sep here with whatever string you want between elements
}
printf "color joined: %s\n", joined
```

I also cleaned up the incorrect use of printf and the spurious semi-colons.

In the above script `split(color, chars, "")` relies on having a version of awk that will split a string into an array given a null field separator, which is undefined behavior per POSIX, but that's not what this answer is about - the question is how to join array elements not how to split them.

Comment: Ah -- right. `sep` is `""` first time through. Nice.

Comment: @dawg : yeah this approach also re-assigns the output `sep` every single cycle of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with POSIX Awk:

```
br = "red,orange,yellow,green,blue"
ch = split(br, de, ",")
print "original: " br
printf "joined: "
for (ec in de) printf ec == ch ? de[ec] "\n" : de[ec] "-"
```

Output:

```
original: red,orange,yellow,green,blue
joined: red-orange-yellow-green-blue
```

Comment: For me, in FreeBSD's awk, this (1) requires parentheses around the inline conditional in the last line, and (2) prints the first field after a newline. I think the failure is because awk doesn't guarantee that array elements will be processed in order. Use `for(i=1;i<=ch;i++)` instead.

Comment: That will shuffle the order of the elements as @ghoti points out, can fail with a syntax error in some awks due to no parens around the ternary, and would fail if the strings being joined contained printf formatting chars like `%` as it's doing `printf data` instead of `printf "%s", data`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want (in your loop) is [string concatenation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html).

Comment: correct, however I wasn't able to udpate my code to use it somehow, as I don't want to print directly but rather keep result in joined valiable

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous answers and less elegant, but easy and short:

```
color = "#FFFF00"
printf "color original: %s\n", color
split(color, chars, "")
for (i=1; i<=length(chars); i++) {
    (i==1) ? joined = chars[i] : joined = joined" "chars[i] # Define separator here
}
printf "color joined: %s\n", joined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Join     ( arrPrm, chrSep,   strRtn, idxArr ) { # return the string of all array elements, separated by this string
  # optional chrSep argument is the separator to use
  # If chrSep is nonempty value        , use that
  # if chrSep is not supplied / is null, default to one space
  # If chrSep is SUBSEP                , use no separator at all
  strRtn   = ""                             # init function result
  if     ( chrSep == ""     )               # when caller did not specify a separator
    chrSep = " "                            # use default                   separator
  else if( chrSep == SUBSEP )               # when caller did yes specify a separator of special flag
    chrSep = ""                             # use no                        separator

  for( idxArr in arrPrm ) {                 # scan all elements
    strRtn = strRtn chrSep arrPrm[ idxArr ] # append separator and current element to function result
  }                                         # done scan elements

  intLen   = length( chrSep             )   # get how many characters to drop from beginning of function result
  strRtn   = substr( strRtn, 1 + intLen )   # keep everything after that number of characters

  return strRtn                             # pass result back to caller
} # Join
```

Comment: This is a fully-commented answer, adapted /simplified from a different question which I cannot find now.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need `join()` function in AWK, just copy and paste this suckless function and be happy:

```
function join(arr, sep) {
    if (sep == "")  sep = " "
    result = arr[1]
    for (k = 2; k <= length(arr); k++)
        result = result sep arr[k]
    return result
}
```