# Read a log file to extract various fields and count the occurence

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cat

I have a logger file like this:

```
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 13794017 with status : 201
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 13794017 with status : 201
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 13794017 with status : 201
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 13794017 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 17696532 with status : 500
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 17696532 with status : 500
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 17696532 with status : 500
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute() 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=1.808 sec
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute()  Scene7 update for 17696532 itemStatus itemsProcessed=1, itemsUpdated=1, timeTaken=
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
2016-06-11 07:34:01.543 98460 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.c.w.b.JobParserBolt - execute EXIT
```

There is a repetition of hundreds of such logs with different partnumbers and status codes. I want to store the distinct partnumbers which have status codes other than 201 to a separate file so that we can monitor it easily. Though I would like to have a count of all 201 Success Posts. So, the sample output that I want from this should look like:

```
No. of partnumbers with Status 201: 1
Partnumbers with Status 500: 17696532, ... , ...
Partnumbers with Status 401: ... ,...
```

I used awk first, but then parsing isn't so easy. Also note that the same partnumber appears multiple times, how can I add a check so that I do not count a single partnumber more than once.

My Code till now:

```
awk -F'Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber :' '{print $2}' file.log |rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

I wanted to extract the partnumber first like this, but I am not able to apply the check to avoid multiple partnumber problem and relate it's corresponding status code with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem solved using awk. See the inline comments for the explanation.

```
awk '/Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber/ {
    # store the results as a multidimensional array with the first key
    # being the status and the key of the second array being the product
    # number. This removes duplicates because array keys must be unique
    arr[$NF][$16]++
}
END {
    # iterate over the 201 status items and count them
    for (item in arr[201]) {
        count++
    }
    print "No. of partnumbers with Status 201: " count

    # iterate over the status array
    for (status in arr) {
        # skip 201 status
        if (status == 201)
            continue
        # join the array by "," for printing
        # taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648609/1032785
        joined = sep = ""
        for (product in arr[status]) {
            joined = joined sep product
            sep = ","
        }

        print "Partnumbers with Status " status ": " joined
    }
}
' foo.log
```

This produces the following output with your sample log file that I added some additional lines to:

```
No. of partnumbers with Status 201: 1
Partnumbers with Status 401: 17623039
Partnumbers with Status 500: 17696532, 17696539
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @jordanm Just wanted to know, what is NF in arr[$NF]?

Comment: @jordanm, What if I have 
2016-06-11 07:34:01.542 98459 [Thread-23-Job-parser-bolt] INFO  JobLoader c.t.commerce.common.utils.APIUtils - Enrichment data updated successful for partnumber : 17696532 with status : 503 Service Unavailable, Then can I use NF or I have to use $20?

Comment: @tanmay2507 You have to use `$20` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Non-*awk*, using **[datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/)** and **[pee](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)**:

```
echo -n "No. of partnumbers with Status 201: " ; \
grep "status : " file.log | pee \
    'grep    ": 201" | datamash -W -s countunique 16'  \
    'grep -v ": 201" | datamash -W -s -g20 unique 16 | \
        sed "s/^[0-9]*/Partnumbers with Status &:/;s/,/, /g"'
```

Output, (using sample data from OP):

```
No. of partnumbers with Status 201: 1
Partnumbers with Status 500:    17696532
```